# Ubuntu 15.04 Mysql Error

Tags: server, 15.04, mysql

I tried to install mysql-server into my Ubuntu server

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

and I also installed phpmyadmin however it didn't work, when I typed the word mysql either with or without any arguments it always said:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

then I tried to remove, purge, install again many times it kept on giving errors I also tried to delete all the files related to mysql, still didn't work then I tried a clean install on a different dedicated server of the same version and it was giving the same exact problem, but I installed it the same way on ubuntu 14.04 and it worked without problems

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
mkdir /var/run/mysqld
touch /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
chown -R mysql /var/run/mysqld
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Comment: I'm surprised, that this works, since `touch` isn't able to create socket files as required by MySQL.